# Different interpretation of 2D and 3D coordinates in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  pics/aline/.style={
    code= {\draw (0,0) -- (#1,0); }
  },
  pics/bline/.style={
    code= {\draw (0,0,0) -- (#1,0,0); }
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \pic at (0,0) {aline=1};
   \pic at (0,1) {aline=1cm};
   \pic at (0,2) {aline=1pt};

   \pic at (0,-1) {bline=1};
   \pic at (0,-2) {bline=1cm};
   \pic at (0,-3) {bline=1pt};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would expect the two outputs to look the same. However, for `aline` 1 seems to correspond to 1cm whereas in `bline` it seems to correspond to 1pt:

[image]

I guess this is due to the interpretation, but I do not quite understand what happens and why.

Comment: This was an old duplicate somewhere that when you mix zero with and without units strange things were happening. But I couldn't find it.

Comment: I read about that in the manual. However, if I change all occurences of `0` to `0pt` the result stays the same.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell (and it doesn't appear to be clear from the manual), any coordinates with three comma separated elements *x* , *y*, and *z* are passed to `\pgfpointxyz`. Each is converted to points and *then* transformed using the x-, y- and z- vectors.

So `1cm` is converted to `28.46274` and *then* transformed using the x-, y- and z- vectors, as the following illustrates.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [blue] (0,0,0) -- (1cm,0,0);
\draw [red]  (0,1,0) -- (28.46274, 1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I guess what this means is that in practice only dimensionless numbers should be used with the `xyz` coordinate system.

One *could* if one was feeling daring, redefine `\pgfpointxyz` to check if the units were given and then divide through by the appropriate vector. This may have unintended side-effects for other code.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\def\pgfpointxyz#1#2#3{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1}%
  \ifpgfmathunitsdeclared\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult/\pgf@xx}\fi%
  \let\pgftemp@x=\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfmathparse{#2}%
  \ifpgfmathunitsdeclared\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult/\pgf@yy}\fi%
  \let\pgftemp@y=\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfmathparse{#3}%
  \ifpgfmathunitsdeclared\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult/\pgf@zz}\fi%
  \let\pgftemp@z=\pgfmathresult%
  \pgf@x=\pgftemp@x\pgf@xx%
  \advance\pgf@x by \pgftemp@y\pgf@yx%
  \advance\pgf@x by \pgftemp@z\pgf@zx%
  \pgf@y=\pgftemp@x\pgf@xy%
  \advance\pgf@y by \pgftemp@y\pgf@yy%
  \advance\pgf@y by \pgftemp@z\pgf@zy}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [blue] (0,0,0) -- (1cm,0,0);
\draw [red]  (0,1,0) -- (28.46274, 1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]